# What's causing try_files to fail her?

Tags: nginx

How does `try_files` not load the file here?

I have this configuration:

```
server {
        server_name test;
        root /var/www/test_dir;
        location / {
                index index.html, index.htm;
                try_files $uri, $uri/, index.html;
        }
}
```

Where root points to the folder `/var/www/test_dir`:

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 17 19:52 test_dir`

which contains the file `index.html`:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 48 Sep 17 19:52 index.html`

I get a 404 error. To verify that Nginx uses this config, I commented the above config  out and reloaded it. Visiting caused a connection error. When I uncommented it out and reloaded Nginx, it gives me the 404 error again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commas aren't needed - they're interpreted in this way as *literal characters* to be included in your try_files or index page filenames. Try and remove all the commas there in your config for index and try_files directives, and use *just* spaces to separate arguments, not commas. (So it's testing the URI `/,` for a bare request to your site and is trying the file named `,` which doesn't exist, and even if that weren't the case for any given URI your index says to look for `index.html,` which also won't exist.)

Config should look like this because in NGINX config files arguments passed to the individual commands/directives are **space-delimited** not comma-delimited:

```
server {
        server_name test;
        root /var/www/test_dir;
        location / {
                index index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
        }
}
```